# Why would you enumerate your OU container names?

Tags: active-directory

> `OU=1.2.1 POS Checkout Line,OU=1.2 POS,OU=Testing,DC=contoso,DC=net`

My boss wants to have enumerated container names in active directory.  I am opposed to it. While I suppose in theory this should work, it very much rubs me the wrong way.  For one thing, I have not seen an example of anyone doing this.  So I don't have evidence that it won't work, and cannot think of a reason not to do it other that its really annoying..

Could I have some feedback.. preferably thoughts on what may not work as a result.For some reason, just proper naming is not good enough for him...

Please advise..

Bad sysop

Comment: It might make scripting interesting if the display name and object are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this isn't a technical problem. Microsoft allows any characters to be used in OUs and it's LDAP client communicates fine with them. You would need to verify you don't have any third party LDAP clients that would choke on special characters.

Here is the MS KB on what is allowed for AD:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909264

Comment: I realize that technically it doesn't break any rules, But it is really annoying to enumerate each container name at each level.... The struggle is real.  I sincerely hope that some system chokes on it.

Comment: Actually no, it is easier - you just enumerate by the NUMBER and ignore the rest. The Number is often following the coding of an organizational diagram, so it is something that for example is hanging in a wall somewhere showing which departments exist.

Comment: But its not layed out that way. Under testing is:
1.1 Servers (with nothing in it)
1.2 POS
inside it is:
1.2.1 POS Checkout lin
1.2.2 POS Window
1.2.3 POS order taking

2.1 Accounting
under it is :
2.1.1 accounting managers
2.1.2 accounting associate
 
2.2 Front End
Under it is :
2.2.1 Frontend Manager
2.2.2 Window Cashier

Just don't see the logic in it..

Comment: I would recommend against that example as it would make managing your group policy tedious. If you grouped similar OUs you could benefit from inheritance and have less gpo links, but it's kind of minor. Being in a PCI environment every change you make will have to be documented and tested anyways.

Comment: We are moving to needing PCI compliance...

Answer (score 1):

1) It doesn't do any harm technically;
2) My boss wants it; 
3) My boss decides how much I get paid

what more I can argue against it?

Comment: my boss doesn't get to support it, I do.
When I have to propose an expected outcome, there are no examples of other people who do the same thing. Because no one does it.
How many cute situations would you like to have in an environment that you have to support before the reason that something doesn't work has to be one of those cute and clever things that no one else does.. that technically doesn't break the rules.. but no one does it..

Comment: I don't see how this naming scheme causes any support issue. What your boss proposed may seem a bit out of ordinary, but I am not sure if anyone can find a legit cause to oppose it, meaning it's something benign, something isn't worth fighting against.